# soap webservice method with an object to be called from android

Tags: java, android

I need to call a soap webservice from my android app.the webservice method has an object with 4 values.I have read about ksoap lib.But i am confused of how the object in service be sent as parameter from android.Please help me solve this.

```
  public SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL,String IP,String SERVICEPATH) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException 
  {

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request

    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();

    pi.setName("Parameter1");
    pi.setValue(Value1);

    request.addProperty(pi);
     pi.setName("Parameter2");
     pi.setValue(Value2);
    request.addProperty(pi);



SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); // put all required data into a soap
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request); // prepare request
envelope.bodyOut = request;
  Log.d("ENVELOPE",""+"Coming3");
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
//androidHttpTransport.
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Log.d("ENVELOPE",""+envelope.bodyIn);
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn; // get response
Log.d("ENVELOPE",""+envelope.bodyIn);
SoapObject responseBodyRaw,responseBody,tableRow;
return result;
}
```

Is this how it should be done?
I have not worked with ksoap and soap webservices.Please help

Comment: Where is your code??? post code at least

Comment: Yes Ksoap lib is good.However what errors are you getting/what problem?have you seen this http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-call-java-web-service-in-android/

Comment: What is format(Structure) in which you have to send the request....?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have webmethod defined like this which returns Category object.

```
[WebMethod]
public Category GetCategoryById(Category C);
```

Say Category class has three properties like CategoryId, Name and Description.So to use it with KSoap you have to implement `KvmSerializable`.

```
package CommonObjects;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class Category implements KvmSerializable
{
public int CategoryId;
public String Name;
public String Description;

public Category(){}
public Category(int categoryId, String name, String description) {

    CategoryId = categoryId;
    Name = name;
    Description = description;
}
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {

    switch(arg0)
    {
    case 0:
        return CategoryId;
    case 1:
        return Name;
    case 2:
        return Description;
    }

    return null;
}

public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 3;
}
public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo info) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
        info.name = "CategoryId";
        break;
    case 1:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Name";
        break;
    case 2:
        info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
        info.name = "Description";
        break;
    default:break;
    }
}

public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
    switch(index)
    {
    case 0:
        CategoryId = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
        break;
    case 1:
        Name = value.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        Description = value.toString();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Now you have to map the properties, read them and write them.

So the web service call is:

```
public void WebServiceCallExample()
    {
        String NAMESPACE = "http://vladozver.org/";
        String METHOD_NAME = "GetCategoryById";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://vladozver.org/GetCategoryById";
        String URL = "http://192.168.1.3/VipEvents/Services/CategoryServices.asmx";

        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        /*
         * Create Category with Id to be passed as an argument
         * 
         * */
        Category C = new Category();
        C.CategoryId = 1;

        /*
         * Set the category to be the argument of the web service method
         * 
         * */
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("C");
        pi.setValue(C);
        pi.setType(C.getClass());
        Request.addProperty(pi);

        /*
         * Set the web service envelope
         * 
         * */
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Category",new Category().getClass());
        AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
        /*
         * Call the web service and retrieve result ... how luvly <3
         * 
         * */
        try
        {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            C.CategoryId =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
            C.Name =  response.getProperty(1).toString();
            C.Description = (String) response.getProperty(2).toString();
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            tv.setText("CategoryId: " +C.CategoryId + " Name: " + C.Name + " Description " + C.Description);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In order to use this code, make sure that you replace the first three variables in this method with your own. NOTE: The SOAP_ACTION could actually be computed as NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME

In the lines about the property info, I show how to actually pass a Category class complex object to KSOAP.

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("Category");
pi.setValue(C);
pi.setType(C.getClass());
Request.addProperty(pi);
```

Regarding the return type, if your web method returns a complex object (such as ours), you need to tell KSOAP how to handle the response. That is done with the following code:

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Category",new Category().getClass());
```

This part of the code is the actual retrieval of the response:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
C.CategoryId =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
C.Name =  response.getProperty(1).toString();
C.Description = (String) response.getProperty(2).toString();
```

Reference from this [blogpost](http://seesharpgears.blogspot.in/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html).

Comment: Hi...thanks for the code..I have 1 more doubt..i have a byte[] and date in the category class...so what should be the type of these values

Comment: I need to add 7 values and it will return a string.So in category class should i set all values?

Comment: hi...i m getting xmlPullParseException:unexpected token @3:15...please help me..resolve it